# adding url dynamically produces syntax error

Tags: angular

i am passing url dynamically in following code which is producing error `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`because url is dynamically added as `https://wizkidtest.daily.co/testcall` but when i harcode url as `'https://wizkidtest.daily.co/testcall'` it works fine, adding url in string '' makes the difference

```
let script = this._renderer2.createElement("script");
    script.type = `text/javascript`;
    script.text = `
        {
          callFrame = window.DailyIframe.createFrame({
        showLeaveButton: true,
        iframeStyle: {
          position: 'fixed',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%'
        }
      });
          callFrame.join({ url: ${this.url} })
        }
    `;
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
```

Comment: you can use directly {url:this.url} -you use the sintax ${expresion}, I think that is `\`${...}\``, enclosed by `\``

Comment: script.text is already in `...`

Comment: Sorry, I read so quick, try `console.log(this.url,script.text)` to see what is the value ofthis.url

Comment: https://wizkidtest.daily.co/ftgRz6okB76OismZAjBF 
        {
          callFrame = window.DailyIframe.createFrame({
        showLeaveButton: true,
        iframeStyle: {
          position: 'fixed',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%'
        }
      });
          callFrame.join({ url: https://wizkidtest.daily.co/ftgRz6okB76OismZAjBF  })
        }

Comment: I think forget the quotes, but I'm not sure `callFrame.join({ url: "${this.url}" })`

Comment: thank you @Eliseo wasted so much time on such simple solution

Answer (score 4):

Since you're passing whole script as string, you need to ensure that your url is wrapped in quotation marks within that script - otherwise it won't be treated as a string, e.g.

```
callFrame.join({ url: "${this.url}" })
```

or

```
callFrame.join({ url: '${this.url}' })
```

Without that, it would create an output of `{ url: https://wizkidtest.daily.co/testcall }` which is wrong.